# Detecting a moving object hitting a stationary object in java

Tags: java, applet, collision-detection

I have a structure full of rectangles that are drawn on the screen by the user, meant to be "blockades" for a ball to bounce off of during runtime. I considered using `Rectangle.intersects()`, but realized that (unless I'm not well enough informed) there isn't a way to tell which way the ball was going when `intersects` returns true. Currently I'm using this large mess of logic to try and detect when the ball touches the edges of a given rectangle, and its not working well at all. If there is a better way to do this, or if there is a way to fix the logic below, I'm open to hear any suggestions with this. Thank you!

```
for (Rectangle rect : r)
    {
      int rx = rect.x;
      int ry = rect.y;
      int rh = rect.height;
      int rw = rect.width;
      //If the ball hits either side of the rectangle, change the x direction
      if((loc.x > rx && loc.x > ry && loc.x < (ry + rh))||(loc.x < (rx + rw) && loc.x > rx && loc.x <(ry + rh)))
        {dx *= -1;}
      //If the ball hits either the top or bottom, change the y direction
      if((loc.y > ry && loc.y > rx && loc.y < (rx + rw))||(loc.y < (ry + rh) && loc.y > ry && loc.y <(rx + rw)))
        {dy *= -1;}
    }
```

For reference, and to make this a bit more readable, r is a Vector containing all drawn rectangles, loc is a Point where the ball currently is, and dx and dy are the direction the ball is moving (either 1 or -1).

Comment: I just banged my head against a very large wall offer a simular question, go check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13261767/java-ball-object-doesnt-bounce-off-of-drawn-rectangles-like-its-supposed-to/13263022#13263022)

Comment: Holy smokes, +1 for that