# Calculating the intersection POINTS between 2 rectangles

Tags: java, math, intersection, rectangles

I've got a problem where i need to find the intersection points of 2 rectangles. I know this question has already been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14616829/java-method-to-find-the-rectangle-that-is-the-intersection-of-two-rectangles-usi), but the solutions always returns a rectangle, whereas i just need the 2 or 4 intersection points

Comment: show your work - what have you done, what is the specific problem, what errors do you get?

Comment: You've got 4 lines for each rectangle.  How hard is it to test whether any two lines (one from each rectangle) intersect?  (And, of course, make sure that the intersection lies along the edge of the rectangle, not beyond.)

Comment: Are the rectangles axis-aligned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps this method offers what you're looking for

```
public List<Point> getIntersects(Rectangle2D a, Rectangle2D b) {
        if (!a.intersects(b)) return null;
        List<Point> points = new ArrayList<Point>();
        double ax = a.getX();
        double ay = a.getY();
        double aw = a.getWidth();
        double ah = a.getHeight();
        double bx = b.getX();
        double by = b.getY();
        double bw = b.getWidth();
        double bh = b.getHeight();
        if (ax <= bx) {
            if (ay < by) {
                points.add(new Point((int) (ax + aw), (int) by));
                points.add(new Point((int) (bx), (int) (ay + ah)));
            } else {
                points.add(new Point((int) (ax + aw), (int) (by + bw)));
                points.add(new Point((int) (bx), (int) (ay)));
            }
        } else return getIntersects(b, a);
        return points;
    }
```