# Java: find position of an object intercepting another object?

Tags: java, types, collision-detection

I am creating and using [Line2D](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Line2D.html) in Java  . I am wondering what Java data type I would use here? Instead of [any points on the line]? Or should I be doing some other logic?

```
if (object.yPosition >= [any points on the line] ) 
    {
        object.yPosition = line.Y_Position; OR object.xPosition = line.x_Position; //set object position = incoming point of interception
        object.Speed = - object.Speed+1; //then reverse incoming object speed
}
```

Comment: Maybe something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13261767/java-ball-object-doesnt-bounce-off-of-drawn-rectangles-like-its-supposed-to/13263022#13263022)

Comment: either distance PointToLine < smallValue or distanceToLineSegment.

Comment: Yes! bounds()! But for a line?                                                                  I've found : Line2D.method (PathIterator getPathIterator(AffineTransform at))
"Returns an iteration object that defines the boundary of this Line2D."            But I have no idea how to use either PathIterator or AffineTransform data types. Help?